# Unwanted Polygon between Polylines in Leafletjs

Tags: javascript, leaflet, polyline

I have created polylines with LeafletJS to connect markers on an openstreetmap. However, when I add more than two points to my polyline function an unwanted yellow triangle appears between the points. (Image and code below)

[image: triangle appears when more than two points in polyline]

Is this a known issue or is there a bug in my code? I've tried looking at documentation and a couple of examples and they do it the same way.

```
    var firstpolyline = L.polyline([[53.095039, -7.921957],
    [51.143901, -1.434145],
    [52.915245, 6.869848]], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Check that you're not using the [`fill` and `fillColor` options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#path-fill) on your polyline.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, I thought those settings were exclusively for polygons, but when I checked your link to the documentation and set fill to false and fillOpacity to 0 it got rid of the yellow triangle. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you have to specify `fill:'false', fillOpacity:'0'` where the color is set to remove the yellow triangle (polygon fill). Now there are just the red lines.

The link to the documentation is here: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#polyline

Comment: Please note that the default value of `fill` is `false` for `L.Polyline`s and `true` for `L.Polygon`s.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder why my map has the fill as yellow as default? Also as a secondary problem which I may have to ask another question about: I can't change the colour of the line no matter what I use...